# Perl Loop Output to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: perl, excel, loops, foreach

I have a Perl script, the relevant bits of which are posted below.

```
# Pull values from cells
        ROW:
        for my $row ( $row_min + 1 .. $row_max ) {
            my $target_cell   = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $target_col);
            my $response_cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $response_col);

            if ( defined $target_cell && defined $response_cell ) {
                my $target   = $target_cell->value();
                my $response = $response_cell->value();

# Determine relatedness
                my $value      = $lesk->getRelatedness($target, $response);

# Copy output to new Excel spreadhseet, 'data.xls'
                my $workbook1  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('data.xls'); 
                my $worksheet1 = $workbook1->add_worksheet();
                $worksheet1->set_column(0, 3, 18);
                my $row = 0;

                foreach ($target) {
                $row++;
                $worksheet1->write( $row, 0, "Target      = $target\n");
                $worksheet1->write( $row, 1, "Response    = $response\n");
                $worksheet1->write( $row, 2, "Relatedness = $value\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

This script uses the Perl modules ParseExcel and WriteExcel. The input data spreadsheet is a list of words under two columns, one labelled 'Target' and the other labelled 'Response.' The script takes each target word and each response word and computes a value of relatedness between them (that's what the

```
$lesk->getRelatedness
```

section of code is doing. It is calling a perl module called WordNet::Similarity that computes a measure of relatedness between words).

All of this works perfectly fine. The problem is I am trying to write the output (the measure of similarity, or $value in this script) into a new Excel file. No matter what I do with the code, the only output it will give me is the relatedness between the LAST target and response words. It ignores all of the rest.

However, this only occurs when I am trying to write to an Excel file. If I use the 'print' function instead, I can see all of the outputs in the command window. I can always just copy and paste this into Excel, but it would be much easier if I could automate this. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: `foreach ($target) ` is a useless loop. `$target` is a single value variable and the loop will only execute once, leaving `$row` at 1 at all times (since it is reset to 0). Also, if you had used strict and warnings, you should have gotten a warning about the second `$row` variable overshadowing the previously defined one.

Comment: I DID use strict and warnings. It didn't give me any error message. Do you have any suggestion for how to replace the foreach loop? Is it possible to save each of the $target and $response values as elements in an array?

Comment: This code would give an error, since you declare `my $row` in two places, within the same scope. If it did not, then something is fishy. The foreach loop as I said is useless, since a scalar value can only ever have 1 value. Without knowing what you are attempting to accomplish, it is hard to say how to fix it. However, since you are (over)writing to the same `$row`, it is consistent that you only see the last value printed.

Comment: I've run it through multiple times with strict and warnings, no error. I've described what I'm trying to accomplish, I don't know how to explain it any further. If a scalar value can only have 1 value at a time, is there a way to convert it to an array? And I'm not overwriting to the same $row, anymore, since $row is no longer set to 0 (see below).

Comment: You should update your question to reflect changes made to your script.

Comment: Anyway, problem is solved. I just needed to move the "my $workbook1  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('data.xls'); my $worksheet1 = $workbook1->add_worksheet();" lines to another part of the script. Since they were in the 'for' statement, the program kept overwriting the 'data.xls' file every time it ran through the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resetting the value of $row each time to 0.

Comment: I took that out and re-ran the script. Same result. With the 'my $row = 0' code, the only output was on row 2. When I took that out, it still only gives me the output for the last data, but now it is bumped down to the 31st row. Which is where it SHOULD be, but why isn't the data filled in for the rest of the rows?

Comment: Billy, try adding a print statement to see if your conditional if statement is being utilized. It's possible they aren't printed because both values may not be defined. Also, if you're generating multiple files, you should probably add workbook1->close() to the end of your for loop

Comment: Thanks, you're right I should have the close statement in there. If I use "print," all of the appropriate values appear.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved. I just needed to move the

```
my $workbook1 = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('data.xls'); 
my $worksheet1 = $workbook1->add_worksheet();
```

lines to another part of the script. Since they were in the 'for' statement, the program kept overwriting the 'data.xls' file every time it ran through the loop.